# Neat way of popping key, value PAIR from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.5

`pop` is a great little function that, when used on dictionaries (given a known key) removes the item with that key from the dictionary and also returns the corresponding value. But what if I want the key as well?

Obviously, in simple cases I could probably just do something like this:

```
pair = (key, some_dict.pop(key))
```

But if, say, I wanted to pop the key-value pair with the lowest value, following the above idea I would have to do this...

```
pair = (min(some_dict, key=some.get), some_dict.pop(min(some_dict, key=some_dict.get)))
```

... which is hideous as I have to do the operation twice (obviously I could store the output from `min` in a variable, but I'm still not completely happy with that). So my question is: Is there an elegant way to do this? Am I missing an obvious trick here?

Comment: store the output from `min` in a variable

Comment: @JBernardo I had thought of that. It is obviously better, but I still feel there should be a better way without one.

Comment: You might want a heap, rather than a `dict`. See the `heapq` module.

Comment: why are you unhappy with using variables?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I don't mind using them, but I'd much rather use a function that can do it in one neat motion. That's why I'm asking- my problem seems so banal that I feel, given Python's reputation, that there should be such a function.

Comment: Sounds to me like if there was a way, it would be an optional argument to `some_dict.popitem()` - but docs give no argument there, so I think there would be no method for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define yourself dictionary object using python [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)s which provides the infrastructure for defining [*abstract base classes*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class). And then overload the `pop` attribute of python dictionary objects based on your need:

```
from collections import Mapping

class MyDict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs))

    def __setitem__(self, key, item): 
        self.__dict__[key] = item

    def __getitem__(self, key): 
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def __delitem__(self, key): 
        del self.__dict__[key]

    def pop(self, k, d=None):
        return k,self.__dict__.pop(k, d)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__dict__.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)

    def __repr__(self): 
        return repr(self.__dict__)
```

Demo:

```
d=MyDict()

d['a']=1
d['b']=5
d['c']=8

print d
{'a': 1, 'c': 8, 'b': 5}

print d.pop(min(d, key=d.get))
('a', 1)

print d
{'c': 8, 'b': 5}
```

*Note* : As @chepner suggested in comment as a better choice you can override `popitem`, which already returns a key/value pair.

Comment: It would be better to override `popitem`, which already returns a key/value pair, and allow it to take an optional key argument.

Comment: @chepner Yes, that would be better. I just showed the way.

Comment: Thanks, accepted as it gave a solution to the general problem.

Comment: I guess storing the key in a variable as suggested by JBernado is preferable to implementing a whole new class.

Answer (score 3):

A heap supports the pop-min operation you describe. You'll need to create a heap from your dictionary first, though.

```
import heapq
# Must be two steps; heapify modifies its argument in-place.
# Reversing the key and the value because the value will actually be
# the "key" in the heap. (Or rather, tuples are compared 
# lexicographically, so put the value in the first position.)
heap = [(v, k) for k, v in some_dict.items()]
heapq.heapify(heap)

# Get the smallest item from the heap
value, key = heapq.heappop(heap)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's great for the minimum, but that was just an example of the more general problem of popping both the key and value, given a certain key (sorry if that was unclear). Ideal solution would able to do the same thing with other criteria.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oops. I knew that, but then while testing something out I got lazy and forgot that `heap` was just a list whose order was amenable to the `heapq` functions, rather than an instance of a distinct heap type.

Answer (score 2):

here is a simpler implementation

```
class CustomDict(dict):
    def pop_item(self, key):
        popped = {key:self[key]} #save "snapshot" of the value of key before popping
        self.pop(key)
        return popped

a = CustomDict()
b = {"hello":"wassup", "lol":"meh"}
a.update(b)
print(a.pop_item("lol"))
print(a)
```

So here we create a custom `dict` that pops the item you want and gives out the key-value pair

Comment: Please add some explanation!